# How to check a string in month year format

Tags: php, datetime

I want to check my string if it is in `fullmonthname year` format.

For example

When `$x= September 2015;` //valid, output should be true
When `$x=Sept 2015;`  //invalid, output should be false

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You could regex the month names in an or `(January|Feburary|etc.)` and then the year. What are years to you `2015`, 4 numbers `\d{4}`, something else?

Comment: <?php
$x="January 2015";

$z=preg_match('/\b(?:Jan(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sept?|September|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)(?:19[7-9]\d|2\d{3})(?=\D|$/',$x);     
print_r($z);die;
?>

Comment: i am getting error Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 180

Comment: You have a few typos try, https://3v4l.org/oIaRM. If that doesn't work update the question to what you have..